# slashes being replaced by \/ on a Zend Dojo Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo

I'am doing this: 
http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/How-to-Zend-Dojo-Form-Dependent-Selects-e-g-Country-City-td663650.html

If i do this:

```
$this->view->form->getElement('subtipo')->setStoreParams(array('url'
=> 'http://localhost/~xpete/project/public/info/lookup/tipo/1'));
```

I get this result on the generated html/js:

```
subtipo_id = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/~xpete\/project\/public\/info\/lookup\/tipo\/1"});
```

The `\` have been replaced by `\/`. 
Is there any way I can avoid this? Is this is a Zend bug?

I tried this with Zend FW 1.11.7 1.11.8 and 1.11.9 preview. 
I tried with both magic quotes on and off and the result is the same. 
I am using php 5.3.7 so magic quote are disabled by default.

`setStoreParams` is a method from the Zend Framework and that's why I think this may be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some links describing some of the behavior you see in PHP:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#100679
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49366

The result is that an flag is being created for PHP 5.4 (which is currently in alpha) to be able to not escape the slashes. I have not seen if this was backported to the 5.3 branch or not.

As the (hopefully) final release of ZendFramework 1 was today, you could modify the Zend_Json::encode method to how you would like. Have it look for strings that start with 'http://' and strip the slashes back off.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a bug. It's common practice to escape a forward slash `/` that is in double quotes to avoid javascript errors. When Javascript writes this as a string, it will only write `http://localhost/~xpete/project/public/info/lookup/tipo/1`

Comment: Javascript has some strange features, but certainly nothing quite as weird as interpreting a forward slash in a string as division. The only significant metacharacters in double-quoted strings are backslashes and double quotes.

Comment: I updated my post, but I don't exactly remember where I read that. Just always was under that assumption. Either way document.write("1/0") is the same as document.write("1\/0");

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace "/" text in user interface using `str_replace("/","",your_string)`.